# Keep first column when inserting new line instead of tab

Tags: linux, awk

I have a text file looking like this:

```
A    one    two    three
B    four    five   six
```

Each separated by tab.

I would like to have each tab has a newline but keeping the first column such as:

```
A    one
A    two
A    three
B    four
B    five
B    six
```

Inserting a new line like I know (awk '{$1=$1} 1' FS="\t" OFS="\n") won't keep my first column

Can anyone help me reformatting my file please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) print $1, $i }' filename
```

The code is quite simple:

```
{                               # in every line
  for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {    # wade through the fields, starting
                                # with the second
    print $1, $i                # and print the first field followed by
                                # the current one.
  }
}
```

The `-F '\t'` option sets the input field separator to a tab, so the line is split at tabs, and `-v OFS='\t'` sets the output field separator to the tab character, so that fields in the output are also separated by tabs.

Then:

```
$ od -c filename     # to show that the input file is tab-separated
0000000   A  \t   o   n   e  \t   t   w   o  \t   t   h   r   e   e  \n
0000020   B  \t   f   o   u   r  \t   f   i   v   e  \t   s   i   x  \n
0000040
$ awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) print $1, $i }' filename
A   one
A   two
A   three
B   four
B   five
B   six
```

Comment: It keeps A for every line and skip totally B. But I guess it is something like this I need

Comment: That's odd; the lines are all treated the same way. Are you sure all lines in the file contain tab-separated data?

Comment: Yes I can extract each column separately using cut -f

Comment: Try leaving out the `-F '\t'` option, does it work then?

Comment: Seems like there was a space in my tab and that was causing the problem, I replaced the space and it now works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks about the tab separated tip!